# Authentication in a mobile app

Tags: facebook, forms-authentication, mobile-application

We are developing a hybrid mobile app (code is written in HTML and runs on browser shell as a native app on the device). We need to authenticate the user against an external security manager. I've seen the Gmail App in iPhone which opens a browser to authenticate the user. We are also looking to do something of that sort. We just need to gather your thoughts on how authentication can be done with some external security manager in a mobile app.

Also I noticed that Dailymotion website was able to know if the user is authenticated with Facebook. This looks like a cross domain authentication.

Can you please share your thoughts on how Google and others have implemented it?

Comment: May I know how did you do this on facebook? I have problem also on implementing facebook authentication on my hybrid app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is OAuth and OpenID services to federate your login. Depending on the architecture of your system you can implement whichever one you like or even a hybrid of both.

Take a look at this link: [Federated Login for Google Accounts](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID)

It provides all the useful information you need.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm this question seems old but in case you haven't found an answer here's how I did it with my hybrid apps :

1. open url on client side with the provider's (facebook/twitter/instagram) url for login
2. the user logs in and is redirected to the server's callback url (my server is written in nodejs)
3. once I've got the access token from the provider. I save this token and then create a token for the client to reuse every time the user wants to access a protected ressource.

Download the [apk](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9GTa-_sqdVJNnZwbzl1TGQxZFE/edit?usp=sharing) and test it.

If this is what you're looking for you can checkout both the client side code at : https://github.com/malikov/Authenticate.me-client-cordova-ionic

And the server side code at : https://github.com/malikov/Authenticate.me-Node-Server

Cheers